# Get best scored result from query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with scored results.  Some of the results have the same score.  I would like to group all the results by the TrackingNumber and select the records with the lowest score.  If there is a tie within the group (min score in group occurs more than once) I don't want to select it.  Here's the tsql to help explain:

```
CREATE TABLE Dupe
(
    Id      INT NOT NULL IDENTITY( 1, 1 ) PRIMARY KEY,
    TrackingNumber  INT NOT NULL,
    Name    VARCHAR(50),
    Score   INT NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT  INTO dbo.Dupe ( TrackingNumber, Name, Score )VALUES ( 1, 'Name1', 1 )
INSERT  INTO dbo.Dupe ( TrackingNumber, Name, Score )VALUES ( 1, 'Name1', 3 )
INSERT  INTO dbo.Dupe ( TrackingNumber, Name, Score )VALUES ( 1, 'Name1', 3 )
INSERT  INTO dbo.Dupe ( TrackingNumber, Name, Score )VALUES ( 1, 'Name1', 5 )
INSERT  INTO dbo.Dupe ( TrackingNumber, Name, Score )VALUES ( 2, 'Name2', 1 )
INSERT  INTO dbo.Dupe ( TrackingNumber, Name, Score )VALUES ( 2, 'Name2', 4 )
INSERT  INTO dbo.Dupe ( TrackingNumber, Name, Score )VALUES ( 2, 'Name2', 9 )
INSERT  INTO dbo.Dupe ( TrackingNumber, Name, Score )VALUES ( 4, 'Name4', 11 )
INSERT  INTO dbo.Dupe ( TrackingNumber, Name, Score )VALUES ( 4, 'Name4', -55 )
INSERT  INTO dbo.Dupe ( TrackingNumber, Name, Score )VALUES ( 4, 'Name4', -55 )
```

Desired output:

```
| ID | TRACKINGNUMBER |  NAME | SCORE |
---------------------------------------
|  1 |              1 | Name1 |     1 |
|  4 |              2 | Name2 |     1 |
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: Can you specify the results you are looking for from this present table?

Comment: can you show your desired output with this dataset?

Comment: What means "If there is a tie within the group (min score in group occurs more than once) I don't want to select it". Do you want to ignore this completely or do you want to take the next higher score that is unique?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter sorry, I just added the desired output. If there is a min(score) tie, I would like to skip that group and not select any record in that group. If there is a tie in a group that isn't a min(score) it should take the row with the min(score) in that group

Comment: @Tanner I just added the desired output and some other clarification

Comment: @Shade I just added the desired output and some other clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My query is a little bit more complicated but it does the job:

```
;WITH tmp (tn, sc) AS
(
    SELECT TrackingNumber, score
    FROM dupe
    GROUP BY TrackingNumber, score
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
SELECT dupe.*
FROM dupe
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tn , MIN(sc) AS s
    FROM tmp
    GROUP BY tn
) t2 ON tn = trackingnumber AND s = score
```

The CTE `tmp` filters out all the records with a single score (since multiple min-scores are not accepted). Then this table is grouped again to find the minimum single score and then joined with the actual sorce table `dupe` again to output all columns.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eadec/5

You can also write it without CTE (just with derived tables):

```
SELECT dupe.* FROM dupe
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT tn,min(sc) s FROM 
   ( SELECT TrackingNumber tn, score sc FROM dupe 
     GROUP BY TrackingNumber, score HAVING COUNT(*)=1
   ) tmp GROUP BY tn
) t2 
ON tn=trackingnumber AND s=score
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eadec/6

Output:

```
| ID | TRACKINGNUMBER |  NAME | SCORE |
---------------------------------------
|  1 |              1 | Name1 |     1 |
|  4 |              2 | Name2 |     1 |
|  7 |              4 | Name4 |    11 |
```

OK, if you want the trackingnumbers with double min-values completely ignored, do this:

```
SELECT dupe.* FROM dupe INNER JOIN 
(SELECT tn, s FROM dupe INNER JOIN
  (SELECT trackingnumber tn,min(score) s FROM dupe 
   GROUP BY trackingnumber) t1
 ON trackingnumber=tn AND score=s
 GROUP BY tn,s HAVING COUNT(*)=1
) t2 ON trackingnumber=tn AND score=s
```

and get this

```
| ID | TRACKINGNUMBER |  NAME | SCORE |
---------------------------------------
|  1 |              1 | Name1 |     1 |
|  4 |              2 | Name2 |     1 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eadec/11

Comment: thanks for all your work! Is there a way to adjust the query so that TrackingNumber 4 is not returned. If there is a tie within a group I don't want any results returned for that group returned